# computer networking error detction cyclic redundancy check

Tags: networking, crc16, error-detection

could anyone tell me that

is it right way if i calculate the crc by the method given below:

i did this because dataword length is large.

[image: hand calc]

[image: hand calc]

is it right?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom set of divisions are what you want for a CRC, and arrive at the correct remainders. Your quotients each need one more bit, but they are not used anyway.

The top division was not completed, but it is not relevant, since you need to append the four zeros first as you did in the bottom left, or the four-bit CRC as you did in the bottom right.

Comment: I have solved this question in my exams.It is of ten marks.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, You are doing the same thing what a division does. Refer https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-Binary-Numbers binary division for more. However, the data word to be sent to the receiver should not be altered.